# Run sequentially jobs by environment using gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I want to run sequentially jobs by environment using gitlab-ci.

Build dev (manual launch) -----> create docker image dev (automatic if dev build works)

Build staging (manual launch) ------> create docker image staging (automatic if staging build works)
...

If the dev build fails, I don't want to create the docker image dev.

How can I do this ? Morever, is it possible to do a for loop to build each environment ?

Here what I currently do :

```
stages:
  - build
  - docker-image

dev:build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build:development
  when: manual

staging:build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build:staging
  when: manual

demo:build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build:demo
  when: manual

dev:image:
  stage: docker-image
  script: 
      - docker build -t registry/project:dev --build-arg environment=development .
      #- docker push registry/project:dev
  when: on_success

staging:image:
  stage: docker-image
  script:
      - docker build -t registry/project:staging --build-arg environment=staging .
      #- docker push registry/project:staging
  when: manual

demo:image:
  stage: docker-image
  script:
      - docker build -t registry/project:demo --build-arg environment=demo .
      #- docker push registry/project:demo
  when: manual
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should [disallow failure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) for the manual jobs so the pipeline will not continue any further on the unsuccessful build.

Manual jobs are allowed to fail by default.
To disallow failure:

```
dev:build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build:development
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

Note:

```
when: on_success
```

on your **dev:image** job is either wrong syntax or does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your help. Actually one part of my problem is referenced here : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40679, I just would like to group jobs and continue the process (build for env then create a docker image and deploy) if it's possible

Comment: Have you considered using different git branches for each environment instead of executing all builds simultaneously?